# Running command in command line works, in bat doesn't

Tags: batch-file

I have the following command that kills a process in port 4200. It works fine if I run it on the command line:

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %X IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr 0.0.0.0:4200') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %X /F
```

But if I put the command in a bat file and run it, I get this error:

`4200') was unexpected at this time.`

How to run the command in a bat?

Comment: What kept you from reading the help file?

Comment: I would suggest that if the port number was the target, then use it alone with `Find`, e.g. `^|Find ":4200"` or continuing with `FindStr`, `^|FindStr ":4200\>"`, or `^|FindStr /E ":4200"`, or `FindStr ":4200$"`. In all cases when using a batch file the percent characters, **`%`**, used for the metavariable, `%X`, should be doubled, i.e. `%%X`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use **%%X** as a variable instead of **%X** when using it in a batch file.

See the following snippet returned when issuing "help for":

```
To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
from %I.
```

Your line would become:

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%X IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr 0.0.0.0:4200') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %%X /F
```

Comment: Do you know what **`.`** means to `FindStr`?

Comment: I missed that in my response. The default search string for FindStr is a regular expression. A regular expression does interpret the character as any character (except new line). So the search expression for the FindStr is probably wrong, but this was not the aim of the question, and therefore I missed it. I would say, go with Compo's sugggestion for the Find/Findstr